# combobox does not run in extjs 4 mvc environment?

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, extjs4, sencha-touch-2

I am trying to get a combobox running, but when I add it to my form, the form does not display.

Here is my code for the form:

```
    Ext.define("Screener.view.Pharmacyform", {

          xtype: 'pharmacyform',
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
    requires: ['Ext.tab.Panel','Ext.form.FieldSet'],

    config:{
         styleHtmlContent: true,
            xtype:'orderform',
            autoscroll: true,


          items:[{
                  xtype: 'fieldset',
                  title: 'Pharmacy Order',

         items: [
            {
                xtype: 'textfield',
                name : 'name',
                label: 'Name'
            },{
                {xtype: 'combo',
    fieldLabel: 'Combobox',
    name:'drugdrug',
    id:'combodrug',

    store: Ext.create('Screener.store.Drugs',{
                            storeId: 'drugstore'

                        }),
                        displayField: 'drugname',
                        valueField: 'drugname',
                        queryMode: 'local',
                        triggerAction: 'all'

        }


              ]
    }]

    }

    });
```

code to drug store:

```
/*
 * This store loads the drugs from file 'drugs.json'
 * Note: there is no writer attached, so changes will
 * only occur in local cache
 */

    Ext.define('Screener.store.Drugs', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    storeId: 'drugStore',

        config: {
            model: 'Screener.model.Drug',
            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                url : 'drugs.json',
                reader: 'json',     
                },
            autoLoad: true

        }
    });
```

I am new to extjs, please tell me how to get it working

Answer (score 0):

You do not specify so much. To be able to help you I need a working sample and the version of sencha you are using.

What I see on a superficial view is you have two stores: The first one is defined 'inline' in the combobox definition. That store is not descendant of Ext.store.Store so it will not work.

The second one seems it is almost correct but it is not used since yoou are instantiating the first one.

Try changing the definition of your store in the view to:

```
...
 fieldLabel: 'Combobox',
    name:'drugdrug',
    id:'combodrug',

    store: 'drugStore'
...
```

Also, you are not saying if you are getting errors in the console.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are referencing a store by name, and you need to load that store before the view is loaded. You have three options:

Reference the store in the controller of this view (.stores[]), and load the controller before the view

Reference the store in application.stores[]

Set the store by reference and not by name, for example:

```
{
xtype:'combobox',
store: new Ext.data.Store({model:'somemodel'}),
...
}
```

The last option is probably better, as combos often work better with their own store. For example there is a bug in 4.1RC2 where you cannot use paging with a shared store. In this case, make sure that you put the proxy on the model, so that there is no code duplication among stores with the same model.

Comment: ok i have tried this,but still facing the same problem , i have created three buttons on home panel,clicking on one of them opens the form,but its not happening when i add the combo box,but other buttons are working fine,when i try to add Ext.form.field.ComboBox in requires [],the application does not load.,is there any problem with the combobox class in the api??

Comment: use firefox. install firebug. are there any errors in firebug? thx

Answer (score 0):

Hey man you should add one statement

renderTo:Ext.getBody()